# Tuple definition in c#

Tags: c#, tuples, definition

I'm trying to define a type that is a `Tuple <int, Tuple <int, int>>`. What I have, is a class named `Tile` where I define some parameters like this:

```
public class Tile
{
    public readonly int producerId;
    public readonly int level;
    public class Id : Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>>
    {
    }
    public class TId : Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>>
    {
    }
}
```

The problem is that VS tells me this for `TId` and `Id`:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'item1' of '`Tuple< int, Tuple< int, int>>.Tuple(int, Tuple<int, int>)`'.

I don't fully understand what is going on here. Do I have to define this type in a different way? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you really intend to make `Id` and `TId` inner classes of `Tile`? Based on their names, I have to wonder if you might've meant for them to be properties of `Tile`. Supposing this _is_ what you want to do, the problem is that `Id` and `TId` do not call a base class constructor.

Comment: FYI there's a [`Tuple<T1, T2, T3>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387150(v=vs.110).aspx) class you could use instead of nesting.

Comment: You should also get your vocabulary right. You don't have any _parameter_ in you class above, but _fields_. [This link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173113.aspx) can give you an overview of class members.

Comment: Yes, fields, sorry for my vocabulario. And yes, my intención is Id and TId to be properties of Tile. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, then I understood you right and you can see my answer. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your code will get confusing and look like a mess in no time. You better define properties in your classes `Id` and `TId` instead of inheriting from Tuple...

If you really wanna go the tuple way, you need to provide parameters to initialize your data :

```
public class Tile
{
    public readonly int producerId;
    public readonly int level;
    public class Id : Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>>
    {
        public Id(int value1, int subvalue1, int subvalue2)
            : base(value1, new Tuple<int, int>(subvalue1, subvalue2))
        {
        }
    }
    public class TId : Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>>
    {
        public TId(int value1, int subvalue1, int subvalue2)
            : base(value1, new Tuple<int, int>(subvalue1, subvalue2))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree with recommendation to not extend Tuple<> for readability

Answer (score 2):

Your class inherits from one which doesn't have a parameterless constructor:

```
public class Id : Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>>
{
}
```

But you define no constructor for your inherited class.  The compiler error is telling you that the default parameterless constructor isn't supplying the necessary arguments to the base class' constructor.

Define a constructor with those arguments:

```
public class Id : Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>>
{
    public Id(int first, Tuple<int, int> second) : base(first, second) { }
}
```

Or, if you want a parameterless one, define default arguments:

```
public class Id : Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>>
{
    public Id() : base(0, new Tuple<int, int>(0, 0)) { }
}
```

Comment: coud even use default(int) instead of 0s

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you don't want to have `Id` and `TId` as inner class, but as a field.

```
public class Tile
{
    public readonly int producerId;
    public readonly int level;
    public Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>> Id;
    public Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>> TId;
}
```

---

Also note that you used a mixed vocabulary in your question. Please have a look [at this MSDN entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173113.aspx) explaining the different class members.

If you want to have the members as *parameter*, not as *fields*, it looks the following:

```
public class Tile
{
    public readonly int ProducerId { get; set; }
    public readonly int Level { get; set; }
    public Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>> Id { get; set; }
    public Tuple<int, Tuple<int, int>> TId { get; set; }
}
```